# Why is &bull; replaced by '/u0095'149 when using request.getParameterMap() in Java?

Tags: java, html, jsp, request, getparameter

I am passing a String value from one jsp to another using the request.getParameterMap() method in Java. The String contains the HTML code for bullet '&bull'  and when I use my debugger to step through I see that the '&bull' has been replaced by a '\u0095'149 and if I do a System.out.println() it appears as a question mark (?). Can someone please help me to figure out what is going on here?

Thank you in advance,
Billy Blanks

Comment: You can't literally have `&bull;` in your request, since in a URL `&` is reserved as the separator between parameter names.  You have to urlencode your parameter value if it contains `&`, so please show the actual url request query (i.e. the `?var1=x&var2=y` part of the url).

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying. I understand, but isn't it possible to do a replace all? Maybe something like [code] some_string.replaceAll("[\\\\u{1}]0095","[\\u]2022") [/code]. By the way, my regex isn't the greatest. I am having trouble catching \u0095. Did I make my regex correctly?

Comment: What I'm saying is I doubt you are really sending the literal text `&bull;` in your request from the client. The translation from `&bull;` to the actual unicode character probably took place on the client before it sent the request.

Comment: I totally understand that the client is using \u0095 as a replacement. Now I want to catch that on the other jsp that I was referring to and replace the \u0095 with \u2022 (should be a round bullet). Will the replaceAll() work for that and if so, is my regex "above" correct? Thank you for your help.